# Grid coordinate issues in print layout

Tags: coordinates, layouts, grids-graticules

I cannot get the grid coordinates to show anywhere near the correct values. Have played around with CRS's and had no luck.

[image: screengrab]

Comment: Your map units are in metres so displaying them as Degrees with suffix will probably be wrong, if you we hoping for degrees there then change the CRS in that panel to ESPG:4326 and then change the interval to 1 or 0.01 or so

Comment: Did you change the CRS of the **GRID** not the project or the layer?

Comment: Ah that CRS works! out of interest is there any way to know which CRS will provide deg etc. as opposed to just meters? * deleted previous comment as I didn't follow instructions!